# PayPal IPN Sandbox - listener not sending request to PayPal - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

Spent the last two days trying to sort this out. It's code I have used many times before with success, but it is failing now. 
I am working with ASP.NET 4.0 on IIS6. 
I am working with the IPN simulator. Here is what is happening.
If I point the simulator to my listener without any code in it I get A-OK!

IF I add the following code:

```
    string strSandbox = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
 string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
 HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strSandbox);

//Set values for the request back
  req.Method = "POST";
 req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;
EM.SendAnyEmail("my@email.com", "String From PayPal ", strRequest);
// I get the above email and life is good
```

But when I add this bit, it breaks:

```
 // code breaks Here????
//Send the request to PayPal and get the response
StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
streamOut.Write(strRequest);
EM.SendAnyEmail("my@email.com", "String Back to PayPal ", strRequest);
// I do NOT receive this email and life is not good
streamOut.Close();

StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
streamIn.Close();
EM.SendAnyEmail("my@email.com", "String Response From PayPal ", strResponse);
```

So something is breaking at:

```
    StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(),       Encoding.ASCII);
streamOut.Write(strRequest);
```

But for the life of me I can't see what the issue is and The "Simulator"
tells me that "We could not send an IPN due to an HTTP Error" But it does not give me an error code.

Here are the Error Messages off of the server.

Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream

TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, 
AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)

I thank you in advance for any help.

Cheers,
GW